# Camera doesn't follow path

Tags: camera, path

I have made a path but can't get the camera to move along it. When I change the offset, some dashed blue lines appear, but the camera stays still.

If I click on some of the other forward axis, the camera disappears "far into the air"

What am I doing wrong? Hope someone can help. I've attached som pictures.

Thanks

Mikkel [image]

Comment: i highly recommend watching a beginner yt tutorial about follow path. Shouldn't be to hard to follow. I assume, you never hit "animate path"?

Comment: Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/